# UEFI boot never runs from /dev/sda but works from rescue DVD

Tags: rhel, uefi, boot-loader, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V on my Windows 10 laptop, with a generation 1 VM running RHEL 7.9.  I am attempting to update it to run on a generation 2 VM, using UEFI boot.

As part of the move to a gen-2 VM, I need to install the UEFI boot code into the /boot partition.

I have the following packages installed, which I think is what I need:

```
grub2-efi-x64.x86_64         (1:2.02-0.07.el7_9.9)
shim-x64.x86_64              (15-11.el7)
grub2-efi-x64-modules.noarch (1:2.02-0.07.el7_9.9)
shim-unsigned-x64.x86_64     (15-9.el7)
```

`efibootmgr -v` shows the following:

[image]

As you can see, I've tried several different configurations via `efibootmgr`, none of which seem to work.

The boot settings for the VM:

[image]

So theoretically, the VM should boot from `\EFI\redhat\shimx64.efi`, which as far as I understand it should be the `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/shimx64.efi` file, which does exist:

[image]

`df -h` shows that `/boot` is mounted on `/dev/sda1` after I `chroot /mnt/sysimage` when booting via the rescue DVD.

As you can see from this screenshot of the /boot partition, there is what looks to me like a valid initramfs file for the kernel (I don't think we're even getting this far though):

[image]

I've also tried resetting grubs config with:

`grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`

The `grub.cfg` file contains menu entries that look correct from a kernel-version perspective, however I never even get to see a grub menu, so again I don't think we're getting this far.  Sounds like a UEFI boot-loader issue to me, but I don't know how to troubleshoot the problem.

When I remove the DVD, and boot the machine, Hyper-V moves down the boot order until it hits the Network Adapter.

[image]

Eventually, Hyper-V shows this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

If I boot from the rescue DVD, then at the grub menu drop to the command-line (via `c`) and run `configfile (hd0,gpt1)/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`, I am able to boot the installed Linux OS.

`mount | grep -i "boot"` from the booted OS shows:

`/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer currently above is pretty good, but does not stress adequately root cause of your issue.

From reading of your information dump, you probably only have linux formatted /boot partition, but that is not enough for UEFI machine to boot.

**Your disk does not match UEFI prescribed layout for bootable disks.**

As was already mentioned above, with UEFI, we are entering a new world of how bootloaders are setup, and requisites are completely different from old BIOS method. UEFI uses completely new partition table format and understands filesystems now(!).

This is simplest set of essential requirements for your disk to be recognized by UEFI firmware as UEFI bootable and booted from:

1. disk must be partitioned with GPT partitioning scheme
2. somewhere on the disk, in the GPT partition table, there must be **one and exactly one** partition present, and it must be marked as `EFI System Partition`, so called ESP; in automated streamlined setups like redhat anaconda, this is often GPT partition 1 of size ~512 MB.
3. this partition must be formatted to a filesystem, whose driver is present inside UEFI firmware (i.e. has been "installed" into the UEFI installation inside of the motherboard chip - this holds even in VM emulated UEFI chip)
4. only UEFI filesystem driver that is always mandatory to be installed (by UEFI spec) in any UEFI install is FAT32, ie it's the safest(/only) bet for ESP to be formatted with
5. on given ESP partition a special UEFI EXE at `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI` (in case of 64bit system) must exist and must be valid runnable bootloader exe
6. if this file is not found there are several other paths that will be inspected, but all of them can be overridden by EFIVAR with custom bootloader exe path; this is what `efibootmgr` is used as editor for.

It seems in your setup you have only one partition, `sda1`, with `xfs` filesystem, mounted into `/boot`.

Your UEFI, naturally, does not have XFS driver installed, thus it is unable to read this partition (and even if it had XFS driver, unless the partition is also of type ESP, it would still not boot from it).

This is my best guess because you forgot to add `fdisk -l`.

**In moden UEFI linux installs ESP is not `/boot`, and it mounts deeper within /boot, like /boot/efi!**

Fix is relatively simple: you need to ensure your partition table is of GPT type (which according to your grub line it already is) and add new partition of `ESP type`, then format it to FAT32, and ensure your `/boot` is not marked as `ESP`. `/boot` should be marked as normal `Linux filesystem` type.

In GPT scheme partition types are UUIDs (but do not confuse them (partition types UUIDs) with partition identifying UUIDs!) so ESP is `EFI System (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B)` type exaclty, while `Linux filesystem` is one of many: for example `Linux root (x86-64) (4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709)`. There is probably one explicit Linux type for `/boot` even.

Now, UEFI only cares for ESP, and as long as it can find it, it will run any UEFI exe it can find there - this "magic" exe is, what used to be called "bootloader" before: it is a program, that is supposed to load your actual OS.

Given "installing" bootloader is now as simple as copying exe onto FAT32 fomratted ESP, the process of bootloader intall got "simpler" for the user. Because UEFI exe is well known format derived from windows PE exe, it is also much easier to write bootloaders now, too. Thus there is also much bigger choice of bootloaders to chose from now.

For few examples:

- refind
- systemd-boot
- gummiboot
- syslinux
- linux(!!!)
- and ... grub

Yes you read right, modern linux kernel, compiled with EFI stub (which most of them are) is fully functional UEFI bootloader. Actually it can boot directly into itself from ESP without need of any intermediatory crap. So you could easily boot directly to linux right from UEFI already.

Unfortunately of all the bootloaders I mentioned here, grub is the probably shittiest possible. Because of this undeniable quality, it is **the go to choice** on 95% linux distributions on the market (this behavior is often the case in linux ecosystem).

The reasons for this choice are often very finicky, it's probably due to useless kernel selection menu at boot start that grub provides and due to the time distributions spent polishing their scripts for integrating new kernel installs appearing in this menu into the package manager.

So now, even after you prepare ESP and format it correctly and you could just boot straigth to linux from it correctly, right away, you have now second big linux booting problem, known as "the grub problem".

GRUB predates UEFI and it solves many booting issues old BIOS had the same way as UEFI does. By now you should realize UEFI is basically its own, Windows 98 level OS, only it is preinstalled directly into the motherboard. It is also very complex.

Same way, GRUB is it's own special mini-OS pre-installed into traditional `/boot` partition (it has it's own filesystem drivers just like UEFI, it's own shell like UEFI, and other stupid things, just like UEFI, only nobody knows/remembers how to use and handle them). You could just ditch it, but as you want your automagic kernel updating to work in conjunction with kernel package updates (through yum/dnf) you need to fix it now.

So in your case this how your boot chain must look like UEFI(OS)->GRUB(OS)->LINUX(OS).

Thus after you fix your UEFI preconditions listed above, you must now fix your GRUB preconditions. GRUB must properly installed into the ESP, so that UEFI can boot into it, and then it must be configured to boot your Linux instead.

Now, where to mount ESP in your in-linux `/` tree for this to work is highly distro dependant, so that is beyond me, but I guess `/boot/efi` is default for redhat family.

So, you need to `rm -rf` that directory in `/boot` that is it empty, and then mount you frshly formated empty ESP with vfat driver there (`/boot/efi`). Once you have that done, you need to chroot into the install, and force local grub to regenerate it's installation in UEFI mode into `/boot/efi` aka "/dev/sda/esp".

This is highly distro specific and also depending on the grub version and can be anything between:

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

to

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdbX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

From within chroot.

If you did right, you should now see GRUB install files appear in originally empty ESP partition and new EFIVAR should/could appear pointing to something like `\EFI\redhat\shimx64.efi` into `ESP` (by UUID).

I suggest to remove all stale boot efivars with `efbootmgr` before grub regeneration/reinstall so you can verify entry added.

Once you are done you should now see grub kernel boot menu after reboot.

Suggested good night readings related to the issue:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/

Comment: `parted` on my distro (RHEL 7.9) doesn't seem to support `esp` as the partition type.  Apparently `boot` is a synonym, which seems to have allowed me to load grub.  However, I probably need to update my grub config since it only loaded in emergency mode.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that with UEFI, there is no such thing as "boot block" any more: *the UEFI firmware can understand filesystems* and **load files**.

The `*.efi` boot file needs to be in a filesystem that is understood by the UEFI firmware (or the hypervisor). The UEFI specification only requires that the firmware **must** understand FAT32; other filesystem types **may** be added if desired.

But RHEL 7.x's default filesystem type is XFS, and HyperV's virtual firmware does not include XFS filesystem support.

So you should add a small partition to your system disk (512M is probably just fine, even less than that might be enough; although I think with modern disks, partitioning disks in units of less than 1 GB is micro-managing), and set it type in the partition table as `0xef` if your system disk is MBR partitioned, or if you use GPT partitioning, just set the partition type as ESP (= EFI System Partition) using your partitioning tool of choice. Then run `mkfs.fat` on the partition, mount it somewhere you can move the current contents of your `/boot/efi` to the new partition, and mount the new partition to `/boot/efi`.

After that, you could use the `efibootmgr` command to clean up your old attempts, then run `grub2-install` again to build a correct UEFI boot variable entry automatically. Alternatively you could do it yourself with `efibootmgr` too, if you wish. Note that the UUID string on the boot entry displayed by `efibootmgr -v` should match the PARTUUID of the FAT32 partition mounted to `/boot/efi`. (You can check with `lsblk -o +PARTUUID`.)

Answer (score 1):

Documenting exactly what I had to do, for future visitors.  Without the details provided in the other answers, this would have been far more difficult.

I was converting my Hyper-V machine from "Generation 1" to "Generation 2".  This big difference there is the boot mechanism goes from the tested, tried, and true method of having the BIOS load the boot sector directly into memory, and executing it, to having the UEFI firmware looking for an "ESP" or "BOOT" partition, and loading an EFI boot file from there.

UEFI boot requires a partition to be marked as bootable by the UEFI firmware, and chances are the UEFI firmware doesn't understand anything but a FAT-formatted partition.  Since Hyper-V is a Microsoft product, it likely understands how to boot from NTFS formatted partitions as well.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 uses the XFS filesystem by default, which cannot be read by the the UEFI firmware.

So, steps I took:

1. Take a backup of my `/boot` file system.  I have a secondary VHDX disk attached to my VM, mounted as `/data`, so I used that as the location for my backup:

   ```bash
   mkdir /data/old_boot
   cp --archive /boot /data/old_boot
   ```
2. Use `lsblk` to determine which device contains the `/boot` filesystem:

   ```bash
   > lsblk
   ```

   ```bash
   NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda             8:0    0   129G  0 disk
   ├─sda1          8:1    0   499M  0 part /boot
   └─sda2          8:2    0 126.5G  0 part
     ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
     ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
     └─rhel-home 253:2    0  68.6G  0 lvm  /home
   sdb             8:16   0   512G  0 disk /data
   ```
3. Use `parted` to drop the existing `/boot` partition:

   ```bash
   > parted /dev/sda
   print
   Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 139GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
   Partition Table: gpt
   Disk Flags:

   Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name       Flags
    1      1049kB  524MB  523MB  xfs          primary    
    2      525MB   136GB  136GB               Linux LVM  lvm
   ```

   In the above, I've started `parted` and executed the `print` command, which shows the list of partitions on `/dev/sda`, so the partition I want to drop is `/dev/sda1` - the size differences between `lsblk` and `parted` is due to `parted` using 1GB = 1,000,000,000 bytes, whereas `lsblk` uses 1GB = 1,073,741,824 bytes.

   This command, run inside the `parted` shell, actually deletes the partition:

   ```bash
   rm 1
   ```
4. Make the new partition, and assign it the `efi` or `boot` flag, to signal the UEFI firmware that this is the partition we'll attempt to boot from:

   ```bash
   > parted
   (parted) mkpart primary fat32 1 524
   (parted) print
   Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 139GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
   Partition Table: gpt
   Disk Flags:

   Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name       Flags
    1      1049kB  524MB  523MB  fat32        primary    
    2      525MB   136GB  136GB               Linux LVM  lvm
   ```

   Set the `boot` flag:

   ```bash
   (parted) set 1 boot on
   (parted) print
   Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 139GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
   Partition Table: gpt
   Disk Flags:

   Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name       Flags
    1      1049kB  524MB  523MB  fat32        primary    boot
    2      525MB   136GB  136GB               Linux LVM  lvm
   ```

   As you can see, the `boot` flag is now set for partition number 1.
5. Next, we'll format the new partition:

   ```bash
   > mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1
   ```
6. We need to ensure that `/etc/fstab` shows the correct items, otherwise we'll get some nasty surprises when Linux boots along the lines of `Timed out waiting for device` and `Dependency failed for /boot`.  We need the partition UUID for the boot device, via `lsblk`:

   ```bash
   > lsblk -o +PARTUUID
   NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT   PARTUUID
   sda             8:0    0   129G  0 disk
   ├─sda1          8:1    0   499M  0 part /boot        93be2242-cfa5-4759-86a8-e563092da88d
   └─sda2          8:2    0 126.5G  0 part              484a1ac4-eba0-49b4-9910-b6471462d8b0
     ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
     ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
     └─rhel-home 253:2    0  68.6G  0 lvm  /home
   ```

   In my case, the partition UUID is `93be2242-cfa5-4759-86a8-e563092da88d` - yours *will* be different, since these identifiers are universally unique by design.

   Next we ensure the `/etc/fstab` file contains the correct partition UUID for the `/boot` device:

   ```bash
   > cat /etc/fstab
   #
   # /etc/fstab
   # Created by anaconda on Mon Jan 16 22:52:23 2017
   #
   # Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
   # See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
   #
   /dev/mapper/rhel-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
   /dev/sda1               /boot                   vfat    defaults        0 0
   /dev/mapper/rhel-home   /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
   /dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
   ```

   In the example above, we see that the `/boot` device is `/dev/sda1`, I needed to ensure that line had `PARTUUID=93be2242-cfa5-4759-86a8-e563092da88d` instead of `/dev/sda1` before the system would boot.  I used [vi](https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/O9WUUSIUJN2fedVEOT7Cuc07dCG-tX53xr6F) to make the change, but feel free to use an editor that doesn't make you crazy.  Once I changed it, the contents look like:

   ```bash
   #
   # /etc/fstab
   # Created by anaconda on Mon Jan 16 22:52:23 2017
   #
   # Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
   # See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
   #
   /dev/mapper/rhel-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
   PARTUUID=93be2242-cfa5-4759-86a8-e563092da88d /boot                   vfat    defaults        0 0
   /dev/mapper/rhel-home   /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
   /dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
   ```
7. Restore the files from the old `/boot` partition, using `cp`:

   ```bash
   > cp --archive /data/old_boot /boot
   ```
8. Update the grub configuration:

   ```bash
   > grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
   ```
9. Install the necessary UEFI boot components:

   ```bash
   > yum reinstall grub2 grub2-efi-x64 grubby shim-x64
   ```
10. Use `efibootmgr` to make an entry pointing at the .efi boot file:

    ```bash
    > efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l '\efi\EFI\redhat\shimx64.efi' -L 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
    ```

    Then take a look at `efibootmgr` to see the list of UEFI boot options:

    ```bash
    > efibootmgr -v
    BootCurrent: 0006
    Timeout: 0 seconds
    BootOrder: 0000
    Boot0000* Red Hat Enterprise Linux      HD(1,GPT,93be2242-cfa5-4759-86a8-e563092da88d,0x800,0xf9800)/File(\efi\EFI\redhat\shimx64.efi)
    ```

At this point I was able to reboot, and Linux booted correctly.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! In cases like these, especially if you have enough of free space on the visor, it is often easier build new Gen2 machine in UEFI mode right away and transfer your settings from one VM to other over the network or some other shared storage. Of course this was also a good learning experience. You successfully manged to fix UEFI in HV VM! Now imagine fixing it on real HW, with its's crappy implementation/of UEFI install, which is usually three times more "fun" ;).

Comment: On the other side, this migration to Gen2 was well worth it, because Hyper-V is one best Microsoft product I have seen so far. If you do `lspci` on your rejuvenated VM, you will see there is now virtually (:)) no(!) PCI "hardware" in the machine, as Microsoft provided Linux with hyper-v drivers for every virtual device, and everything in a VM is paravitual - which has many implications, but especially for a VM performance.

Comment: Agreed.  In my case I had to migrate to gen-2 since BIOS (gen-1) wasn't supported by the target OS.